# When I pass to another radio button both buton's values come

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I want to do two radio buttons. Their names will be car and home. If I click car, an input box about the car section will be shown and if I click home, an input box about the home will be shown.

I have found an example about this and I have a problem about it. The codes are below.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(obj, a)
    {
        var e=document.getElementById(a);
        if(!e)return true;
        e.style.display="block"
        return true;
    }

    function toggleMe2(obj, a)
    {
        var e=document.getElementById(a);
        if(!e)return true;
        e.style.display="none"
        return true;
    }
</script>
<form name="theForm">
    Type<br>
    <input type="radio" name="married" value="yes" onclick="return toggleMe(this, 'Car')"> Car
    <input type="radio" name="married" value="yes" onclick="return toggleMe(this, 'Home')"> Home<br>
    <div id="Car" style="display: none; margin-left: 20px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Car InputBox</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="Home" style="display: none; margin-left: 20px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Home InputBox:</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Output of these codes

If I click the car first, the input box of the car section is shown. If I click the home first, the input box of the home section is shown. After I click the car or home first (doesn't matter) if I click another one, both input boxes are shown.

How can I solve this problem? When I click home, the home input box should be shown and when I click car, the car input box should be shown as well. Not both of them.

Comment: I removed a big chunk of code that had nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="car" onclick="toggleInput(this)" /> Car

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="home" onclick="toggleInput(this)" /> Home
</div>
<div id="car-input-group" class="hide">
    Car InputBox
    <input name="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="home-input-group" class="hide">
    Home InputBox
    <input name="name" type="text" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggleInput(obj){
    var a =document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(obj.value + "-input-group").style.display = "block"
}
```

**css**

```
.hide{
    display: none
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPdTldCXG0LTJWEtzIxE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the example. It makes your solution clear

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Using jquery it's easier. I made it universal, so you could add more radio buttons (using myradio and myinput css classes) without touching the JS.

```js
$( "input.myradio" ).click(function() {
    $( "div.myinput").hide();
    $( "div#"+$(this).attr('id')).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="theForm">
    Type<br>
    <input id="Car" type="radio" name="married" class="myradio" value="yes" />Car
    <input id="Home" type="radio" name="married" class="myradio" value="yes" />Home<br>
    <div id="Car" class="myinput" style="display: none; margin-left: 20px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Car InputBox</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="Home" class="myinput" style="display: none; margin-left: 20px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Home InputBox:</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nqn54z4/)

Comment: Cool animation! :) Thanks!